# How can I insert a comment form into my view?

Tags: views, comments

In Drupal 7, I'm building a module that has a view page that lists all nodes of a certain type. I want users to be able to comment on each node in the view from this view page.

I tried using `hook_node_view` but it only seems to apply to the full node page view. What kind of hook do I need to get the comment form of a node in a view?

Answer (score 2):

What I know? That you can use the view.tpl.php file and add:

```
<?php
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form("comment_node_**content_type_machine_name**_form", (object) array('nid' => **$node->nid**)));
?>
```

Change the bold according to your node object and the content type machine readable name.

I think [this link](http://adaptivethemes.com/print-comments-anywhere-and-the-form-as-well) can help you too. and I suggest to check `hook_views_pre_render` [Here](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) which can do it but I didn't try it before.

Comment: Thankyou, I must apologise but I'm building a module - so I can't put this in the theme template. I need a hook to override the theme some how?

Comment: You can check this answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53689/1431 to see how you can override a template from your own module and then try the solution mentioned here.