# Override field template with custom module

Tags: 7, entities, theming

Instead of adding tpl files (in this case, media-youtube-video.tpl.php) to the theme. How can I override field templates from a custom module? Including when the field is used in a View.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sure there must be an easier way to do this but this is what I typically do:

1.
*Register* an overriding theme implementation with the Drupal theme registry. So, in `mymod_theme()`, add a new item. The `variables` key must match that of the `media_youtube_video` theme i.e.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymod_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_media_youtube_video' => array(
      'variables' => array('uri' => NULL, ...), // see media_youtube_theme() for this
      // bundle the template file with the module itself
      // i.e. theme/my-media-youtube-video.tpl.php
      'template' => 'my-media-youtube-video',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymod') . '/theme
    )
  );
}
```

2. 
*Add* a preprocess hook for the original theme implementation and *suggest* your new implementation here.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_preprocess_media_youtube_video().
 *
 * Or more generally, hook_preprocess_THEME().
 */
function mymod_preprocess_media_youtube_video(&$variables) {
  // If your overriding implementation is not a template but 
  // is implemented in a different file, 
  // then remember to include the file explicitly at this point..
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'my_media_youtube_video';
}
```

Suggestions are evaluated by the theme system in a [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO) fashion. You can read more about this [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7).

Suppose you are aware that another module is also following the same approach as this one to override the implementation, then you can implement `hook_module_implements_alter()` and force your `hook_preprocess_THEME()` (see above) to be called last. You can read about `hook_module_implements_alter()` [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7).

This holds good for Views also. In summary, you just need to find out the correct unique name of the original theme implementation you want to override (typically defined in the source module), add a preprocess hook and add your overriding suggestion there.

Comment: In my custom module, I've a select list for selecting the template to apply. I have 3 tpl files. So How can I do this.

Comment: How can we override body field of node form if there are many node types?

Answer (score 4):

You can also decalare new theme in module this way:

```
/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function yourmodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();

  $theme['field__field_nameofyourfield'] = array(
    'render element' => 'content',
    'base hook' => 'field',
    'template' => 'field--field-nameofyourfield',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'yourmodule') . '/templates',
  );

  return $theme;
}
```

Then put in a /template directory file that contains field template like this (standard) and name it field--field-nameofyourfield.tpl.php:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

After clearing cache your theme will use this filed template unless it's not overriden by theme itself, which means you can still override this template in your theme.