# How to override a module theme function in a custom module but still allow themes to override the template file?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm writing a fairly simple module which allows the removal of colons from field output on a per field basis and I need to override the core field module's theme_field function in my module.

I can modify the theme registry with hook_theme_registry_alter() and change the field function to point to my custom function. Unfortunately once I do that I'm no longer able to override field.tpl.php in a theme.

The cascade I'd like to achieve is in order of template preference (most important first):

1. Active theme's field.tpl.php
2. My custom module's field.tpl.php (or custom_field theme function)
3. Field module's theme_field function

Is this possible?

[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53680/override-field-template-with-custom-module) comes close but requires a differently named template which I don't want. I'd like to keep things clean for the themer so if they override field.tpl.php in their theme the output is as expected, rather than having to copy a different tpl file from my custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Think what you describe could work without falling back to the field module's function:

1. Add `<?php function MODULENAME_preprocess_field($variables) ?>` and set a $colon variable with either `':'` or `''`
2. Copy the theme_field function in your module and rename it `<?php MODULENAME_field(&$variables) ?>`
3. Replace the code that renders the label with: `<?php $output .= '<div class="field-label"' . $variables['title_attributes'] . '>' . $variables['label'] . $variables['colon'] . '&nbsp;</div>';?>`

Might also just document for themers that in the template file they should use $colon for the module to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. I am just going to post from the top of my head.

### Replacing the theme function

> I can modify the theme registry with hook_theme_registry_alter() and change the field function to point to my custom function. Unfortunately once I do that I'm no longer able to override field.tpl.php in a theme.

You can use hook_theme_registry_alter() for this.
You just need to make it conditional. Something like this:

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$registry) {
  if (!isset($registry['field'])) {
    // Perhaps field module is not even enabled, or something else is wrong.
    return;
  }
  if (!isset($registry['field']['function'])
    || 'theme_field' !== $registry['field']['function']
    || isset($registry['field']['template']
  ) {
    // Apparently a theme has overridden the theme hook.
    return;
  }
  // Override with custom module-based template.
  $registry['field']['template'] = ...
}
```

This has a limitation if other modules or the theme itself also use hook_theme_registry_alter() to modify the same hook. But otherwise it should be ok.

You need to experiment a bit with the code above, I wrote this without any testing. Let me know if something can be corrected.

### About the "cascade"

Some additional explanation.

> The cascade I'd like to achieve is in order of template preference (most important first):
>
> - Active theme's field.tpl.php
> - My custom module's field.tpl.php (or custom_field theme function)
> - Field module's theme_field function

The good thing is that this cascade is rather "fixed". The theme registry is stored and calculated per theme, and within a theme the cascade always has the same outcome. The theme template either exists or not. The template in your custom module always exists. So the "Field module's theme_field function" is completely out of the picture.

It gets a bit more complicated if we are dealing with theme overrides like field--body.tpl.php, but we don't need to go into his territory here I think.

### Alternative: Display suite field templates

> I'm writing a fairly simple module which allows the removal of colons from field output on a per field basis and I need to override the core field module's theme_field function in my module.

I should point out that alternatives exist to what you attempt to achieve.

[Display suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) is an excellent module which provides settings for how a field should be rendered. Especially, if you enable ds_extras, go to admin/structure/ds/list/extras, and enable "Field Templates". This is a very powerful tool worth learning more about.

[Renderkit](https://drupal.org/project/renderkit) has "field display processor" plugins, but this goes far beyond what you probably need.