# Theme_hook_suggestions not working

Tags: theming

I'm using hook_preprocess_node in a module. In that, I check whether the node type, and on satisfying the condition I'm doing a theme_hook_suggestions. My tpl.php files are inside my modules template folder, It is not taking the tpl file I have suggested. I have searched a lot, but didn't find any solutions

Any solution would be apprecaited
Here is my code

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$varaiables) {
  if (isset($varaiables['node'])) {
    $node = $varaiables['node'];
    $field_template_list = $node->field_template_list[$node->language][0]['value'];
      if ($node->type == 'event') {
        $varaiables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'module_name_' . $field_template_list;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you be sure $node->field_template_list[$node->language][0]['value'] always has a value? Also, what is in that field? You'll want to make sure to handle any punctuation etc. that users might be able to enter.

Comment: What is the file name of the template file you are trying to use that isn't working as you expect?

Comment: @rooby. 1. I have dpm the value. It have value. 2. File name I'm using is module-name-$field_template_list.tpl.php. Sorry there is a mistake in the code I have included. I'll update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal will not look for template overrides in custom modules, only themes.

If you really want to put a template override in a custom module see the answer to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/53680/10729).

Extra notes are:

- Make sure to handle punctuation and any other undesirable characters in your field value.
- field_get_items() is a better way to get the value of a field from a node.
- It is generally best to keep your template suggestions in line with what is already there. For example starting this suggestion with 'node__' followed by your custom stuff, like maybe `'node__event__' . $field_template_list` or something like that. It makes it easier in future to know what kind of template it is.