# How do customize the HTML output around a specific field using field.tpl

Tags: 7, entities

I in the middle of creating a content type with multiple fields. All the fields need to have all the extra markup removed, except for a specific 3 and I would like these to actually be wrapped in `<h3>` tags.

I've copied the `field.tpl` file into my theme and renamed to be used just for this specific content type, which is working fine with this code:

```
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
  <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?> </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
  <?php print render($item); ?>    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My trouble is that I have no idea the syntax I need to target a specific field. So I'm im guessing once I figure out how to target the specific field, I can just use:

```
  <?php foreach (something here to find the right field): ?>
  <h2><?php print render($item); ?></h2    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

What would that be if my field name was `field_sizing_title`?

I found the [Field Wrappers Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_wrappers), but it seem like overkill and I really like to learn more about how to work with the `field.tpl` file

Answer (score 2):

You need identify the field machine name. For example if you have a field called `Name` and have a machine name `field_name` the field tpl name should be `field--field-name.tpl.php`.

See [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53680/override-field-template-with-custom-module) as well as it provides a comprehensive guide on how to override field template using `hook_theme` and `preprocess` function.

One of the most handy helper I used is `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` in `settings.php`. It will show a template suggestion in HTML source.

Comment: Do I have to have a separate field specific field.tpl file? I already have the one that's targeted to that specific content type. Seems I should be able to use that to target individual fields throughout that content type.

Comment: No need to have individual tpl for each field as you are not overriding them. This only applies to specific field that you want to override.

Comment: So if I have 3 fields I want to override, I need 3 seperate tpl files? I cannot override those 3 individually in the one content type focused field.tpl file?

Comment: In my experience given your scenario, yes I will have 3 separate tpl files. I would avoid mixing them for maintainability. I might be wrong with your use case.

Comment: So, this didn't work for me. I tried adding the `fieldname--field.tpl` file and it never altered the output. I checked and triple checked naming conventions. Is there a priority of themeing here? I didn't delete my `node--field.tpl` while I was working on the field specific file.

Comment: Be sure to clear the cache and if you have PHP accelerator clear it as well.

Answer (score 1):

To find the right field, you should use [`template_process_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) to load it first and expose into your template file as variable.

Here is example using with [Entityforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform):

```
/**
 * Implements template_process_HOOK().
 */ 
function mymodule_preprocess_myfieldhook(&$variables) {
  $entity = $variables['form']['#entity'];
  $field_name = $variables['form']['#field_name'];
  $variables['info'] = field_info_field($field_name);
  $variables['instance'] = field_info_instance($entity->entityType(), $field_name, $entity->type);
}
```

Then you should have in your TPL file two extra variables: `$info` and `$instance` where you can access some field settings.